# Power Query : Add Week column using the column position

Tags: position, powerquery, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column with the day of the week, from another date column.

This code works :

`#"Add DAY OF WEEK" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add DAY", "WEEK DAY", each Date.DayOfWeek([DATE_JOURNEE_PRODUCTION], Day.Monday))`

But I cannot replace the name of the date column (called DATE_JOURNEE_PRODUCTION) by the position of this column in the table.

I'm trying to replace the code for something like

`#"Add DAY OF WEEK" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add DAY", "WEEK DAY", each Date.DayOfWeek(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Data"){1}, Day.Monday))`

But this Table column names is not working.

Anybody could help me ?

Thank you !

Create a new column using the position of another colum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
each Date.DayOfWeek(Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Data"){1}), Day.Monday)
```